# Magento 2 : USPS Unable to read response, or response is empty

Tags: magento2, shipping, configuration, usps

I signed up for the shipping API of USPS and put my test credentials from Magento 2 admin panel. Still I am unable to fetch the shipping rates for USPS carrier. On front end it shows -

[image]

The error reads as - "**This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.**"

After checking in log folder in debug.log, I found this entry -

[image]

The log file reads - "**Unable to read response, or response is empty**"

I have been scratching head for about 4 hrs now. I am pretty sure my credentials are correct. What could be possibly wrong?

I am using Magento ver. 2.0.13.

Hugely appreciate any help :)

Comment: Item has weight?

Comment: @Ankit Yes it has weight. The container size is set to regular.

Comment: I think issue with configuration. http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/usps.html / https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-usps-carrier-magento-2.html

Comment: @Ankit The input in admin panel is exactly the same as described in this tutorial. Still no luck :/

Comment: Which Magento version you are using? I was able to make it work on v2.1.5

Comment: HI @BGKavinga I am using Magento ver. 2.0.13. Can the version be an issue?

Comment: @PiyushDangre, I can't be sure about that. Some of the admin configuration settings are different. I only had to add my user id and it starts showing shipping rates in the front.

Comment: @BGKavinga Exactly that is not happening to me.

Comment: @PiyushDangre It is working on 2.0.13 as well. Check whether you have curl module is installed and enabled.